# MVC post with data and return json data

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a controle like this

```
public JsonResult GetSizes(long Id)
    {
        try
        {
            //get some data and filter y Id

        }
        catch (Exception ex) {  }
        return Json(//data);
    }
```

I need to get that by following json by ajax request

```
var sizes = [];
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    async: false,
    data: { 'Id': selectedId },
    url: "/<Controler name>/GetSizes",
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert('Error: ' + xhr.statusText);
        return false;
    },
    success: function (result) {
        if (result.Result != null) {
            if (result.Result.length > 0) {
                sizes = result;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

But this give me an Server error. How can i fix this.

Comment: what is the `Server error`? Can you post that? and `GetSizes` doesn't help to figure out problem

Comment: I hope that this line `url: "/<Controler name>/GetSizes",` has the correct controller name in it and not this `<Controler name>` placeholder. Otherwise, there's your error source. On a different note, generate the url using `"@Url.Action("controller_name", "action_name")"` by filling in the correct controller and action names.

Comment: Controller name is correct. But it give "Error: Internal Server Error"

Comment: i think problem with data return. return statement with  `return Json("data", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` add `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` in json return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace your

```
url: "/<Controler name>/GetSizes",
```

by

```
url: "@Url.Action("GetSizes", "Controller_Name"),
```

and is you Ajax will have to be

```
async: false?
```

then try to use this as your Action

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult GetSizes(long Id)
{
    try
    {
        //get some data and filter y Id

    }
    catch (Exception ex) {  }
    return Json(//data);
}
```

Also, try to put a break point on your action and see in debug mode if your Ajax reaches your Action.

Answer (score 0):

this my demo, you can do the same:

```
$.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("CheckCity", "BookingStarts")',
                        data: { packageId: packageid, cityId: valuecities[valuecities.length - 1] },
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success:
                            function(result) {
                                if (result.Status == true) {
                                    $('#CheckoutDateHotel_@item.CityId').val(result.Date);
                                }
                            }
                    });
```

in controller :

```
 [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
```

public ActionResult CheckCity(int packageId, int cityId)
{

```
var packageCityModel = PackageDetails.GetPackageCitiesByPackageId(packageId).OfType<HMSService.PackageCity>();
var package = new PackageReservationMasterDal();
var itemPackage = package.GetPackageDetailByPackageId(packageId);
var result = "";
var city = packageCityModel.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CityId == cityId);
if (city != null)
{
    result = itemPackage.TravelDateFrom.AddDays(city.NoOfNights).ToShortDateString();
}
return Json(new { Status = true, Date = result });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

See the problem here is that you have not *stringified* your Data Transfer Object(DTO).
A cleaner approach will be this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json3/3.3.0/json3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var sizes = [];
    var DTO = { 'Id': selectedId };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        data: JSON.stringify(DTO),
        url: "@Url.Action("GetSizes", "Home")",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json'
    }).done(function(result) {
        if (result.Result != null) {
            if (result.Result.length > 0) {
                sizes = result;
            }
        }
    }).fail(function(xhr) {
            alert('Error: ' + xhr.statusText);
            return false;
    });
</script>
```

Please note the use of

1. JSON.stringify
2. @Url.Action helper
3. jqXHR.done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {});
4. jqXHR.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {});

Also you are using `async=false` which I guess is to grab all the `sizes` before exiting from the function. [jQuery.deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) will be an interesting read.